# Magnetic field around a coaxial cable : Dealing with thicknesses

Tags: homework-and-exercises, magnetic-fields, electric-current

[image: Question]

How can we obtain the answer here? How can we deal with the thicknesses here?

Thank you!

Comment: Homework-like questions should ask about a specific physics concept and show some effort to work through the problem. We want our questions to be useful to the broader community, and to future users. See our meta site for more guidance on how to edit your question to make it better

Comment: Thank you! I tried out with the question but I do not know how to deal with the thicknesses here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is easier than you think, and you don't have to worry about the thickness because your interested in the field OUTSIDE the conductor. I'm sure by now you know that the easiest way to solve this is by using Ampere's law. Our closed loop will be a circumference of radius r (distance of point P to the center) and Ampere's law tells us that: 
$$\oint _C {\bf B}\cdot d{\bf l}=\mu _0 I_{enclosed}$$

As for the first integral, since B is uniform through our curve, it will simply become $$B2\pi r$$

Now for $I_{enclosed}$ what is it? It's the current the traverses our closed loop. Now if we have a current I going on one direction in one conductor, and the same current I going in the opposite direction in outer conductor the currents will cancel out (notice that they give you the total current I not the density of current (meaning that the dimensions don't matter).

So that will lead up to a B of zero. 
The remarkable conclusion is that it doesn't matter how thick the outer or the inner conductor are, if they are traversed by the same current but in opposite directions the B field will always be zero. I hope this helped.

Inside the cable the scenario will be different if you want to we can work on that too.

EDIT1: OOPS I forgot to add the permeability of vacuum on Ampere's law. My apologies

EDIT2:
So let's see what's happening inside the cylinder. For that we take the same considerations as before: circular closed loop centered in the axis of the cable now with an arbitrary radius r.

For all of the cases we will consider, the left side of Ampere laws always results on

$$B2\pi r$$

So the difference will lie on our $I_{enclosed}$

For $r<a$ you will need the current density that goes through that current. That will be given by the total current divided by the section on the conductor (think of it as water through a pipe, the flux of water in that quantity divided by the section of the pipe). That is $\frac{I}{\pi a^2}$. Now that you have your density you multiply it by the section of your current loop (you now think of the loop as a disk). You will then have
$$I_{enclosed}=\frac{I \pi r^2}{\pi a^2}$$

Putting everything together ´

$$B2\pi r=\frac{\mu_0 I \pi r^2}{\pi a^2}$$

so

$$B=\frac{\mu_0 I r}{2 \pi a^2}$$

The direction of B is given by the right hand rule, so it's clockwise.

Now the situation of a

For b

And putting everything together leaves you with 
$$B=\frac{\mu_o I}{2 \pi r}(1-\frac{r^2-b^2}{c^2 - b^2})$$

The direction of B I will also leave up to you now :)

Tell me if there were any questions left, did you understand everything?

Comment: Thank you very much! It would be great to know the scenario inside the cable too..

Comment: You're very welcome. Check my edits then :)

Comment: I totally understood what you said. Thank you very much for your effort.. The problem I had is that we do not have Ampere's Law in our syllabi due to lack of Integral knowledge of Biology students.. We do only have derived equations given in the Syllabus..

Comment: Man that really sucks, I'm studying engineering and we can't take Electromagnetism without first succeeding in Mathematical Analysis 3 (so multiple integrals, stokes theorem, divergence theorem, etc.). It must be even harder for you guys. Did you understand how I integrated the B field above? Glad that I helped!

Comment: Also I'm curious about your answers to my questions: what did you get for B between a and b and for the direction of B between b and c?

Comment: a to b is Anticlockwise and b to c is Clockwise...isn't that correct?

Comment: I understood how the Integration was done but we never learn that much theorems... Poor biology guys

Comment: No it's not correct. I was expecting you to make that mistake because I made it some time ago when I was studying this exact problem. Here's the thing: what determines the direction of B is the net current. And from b to c the current that is "dominant" is the current on the conductor of radius a. The other current is "fighting back" but is never greater than the current in the inner conductor (in the limit it will be equal and that's when we're out of the conductor and the net current is zero)! I hope I was clear :D

Comment: Yeah, it's normal that you guys suffer more in terms of these equations. We already suffer and we are apparently not supposed too... Anyway I'm also studying this now so feel free to PM me whenever you want, we can help each other out :)

Comment: I am new here and I don't know how to PM someone here

Comment: You apparently need to have a certain amount of points to start a chat room. Do you have reddit? We can talk there.

Comment: No I don't..but I'll get it

Comment: Ok, when you create it give me the link so I can start a chat room with you.

Comment: Sure, thank you. I'm glad as there are people who are willing to help